# Do any spacecraft use GNSS for attitude determination?

Tags: attitude, gnss, gps

In principle, by placing a GNSS-receiver on all extremities of a spacecraft (or aircraft, for that matter), one can determine the orientation of the satellite.  Google [lists some studies](https://www.google.com/search?q=gnss+based+attitude+determination), but have such systems been used in real spacecraft?  On the one hand, I'd think cubesats might go for such a low-cost solution, on the other hand, the smaller the spacecraft, the larger the error in attitude determination by using GNSS.  The technique is not listed on [the Wikipedia page on attitude control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_control).  Has this been used in practice at all?

Comment: Attitude is kind of a large term, I think specifically you want to know if they have used it to figure out the orientation of the satellite.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Yes, well, orientation and its derivative.  What else is the term used for?

Comment: To me, part of the attitude includes the location of the satellite. And I could give you plenty of examples of satellites that use GPS to figure out where they are. But the orientation is a bit trickier, making it a far more interesting question.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto "**The *attitude* of a spacecraft is its orientation in space.**" First sentence in *Wertz, J. R. (ed.), 1978. Spacecraft Attitude Determination and Control*. It does not include the location.

Comment: @ernestopheles Does it include the time derivative of attitude, i.e. the rotation?

Comment: @gerrit: Sure it does, attitude depends on time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ISS does it. Source: http://spacestationlive.jsc.nasa.gov/handbooks/adcoHandbook.pdf

> Attitude Determination
>
> How am I currently oriented?
>
> The ISS also uses GPS to determine how the ISS is
>   oriented, or facing, as it orbits the Earth. **This
>   orientation, or attitude, can be determined by
>   measuring the difference in time that the GPS signals
>   are received by four antennas**. These antennas
>   receive the same GPS signal at slightly different times,
>   with the signal traveling at a constant speed (the
>   speed of light).
>
> To calculate attitude, at least four of the nearly 24 GPS
>   satellites in orbit must be in view of these antennas.
>   **The GPS receiver calculates the ISS attitude about
>   once a minute**, providing information on where the ISS
>   is pointed at that point in time.

Now, in more detail on that:

http://sunnyday.mit.edu/16.355/Gomez-GPS-Lessons.pdf

> The ISS GPS antenna array consists of four antennas in a
>   3 meter by 1.5 meter rectangle on the S0 element of the
>   ISS main truss. The array center is slightly to the port
>   side (4 meters) of the vehicle centerline, as shown in
>   Figure 10.

[image: Figure 10]

[image: ISS in orbit]

> **GPS alone can not meet the attitude
>   accuracy requirements. The multipath environment on
>   ISS is such that the unfiltered GPS attitude solutions can
>   not meet the 0.5 degree requirement. The unfiltered GPS
>   attitude solutions are used as an input in the ISS’s on
>   board software attitude filter.**

Comment: You'd have thought that they'd put the antenna's on the corners of the solar array, to get a better baseline and less multipath effects.

Comment: Those arrays were not there all the time, they were added gradually as the station was built.  Attitude control was needed all the time.  To accomplish your suggestion the antennas would have needed to be relocated multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

The new Soyuz MS does too.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_MS

> Instead of relying on ground stations for orbital determination and
>   correction, the now included Satellite Navigation System ASN-K
>   (Russian: (АСН-К, Аппаратура Спутниковой Навигации) relying on GLONASS
>   and GPS signals for navigation.[2][11] It uses four fixed antennas to
>   achieve a positioning accuracy of 5 m (16 ft), with the objective to
>   reduce that number to as little as 3 cm (1.2 in) and an attitude
>   accuracy of 0.5°.[12]

Comment: I don't doubt that this is true, but I'm having difficulty verifying this from the sources listed, so I've asked a follow-up question. [Does the Soyuz spacecraft really achieve attitude accuracy of 0.5° from GLONASS and GPS signals?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31193/12102) which is in pursuit of trying to resolve if there is a satellite using this as well, as asked in [Current status of the use of GPS mutli-antenna time differentials for attitude determination?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31185/12102)